# Imágenes de fondo de tailwind no funcionan al hacer build con vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind, vite

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que usa **Tailwind**, **Vite** y **React**.

Cuando desarrollo en **dev** la imagen de fondo se ve correctamente, pero cuando hago el **build** la imagen de fondo no se muestra y es porque después de compilar sigue buscando la ruta de **dev** la cual ya no existe.

Esta es mi configuración de **Tailwind**

```
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        black: '#000000',
        white: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        'RobotoSlab-Regular': ['RobotoSlab-Regular'],
        'Agrandir-WideBlackItalic': ['Agrandir-WideBlackItalic'],
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'footer-background': 'url(./src/assets/images/footer-background.jpg)',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Esta es mi configuración de **Vite**

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), eslint()],
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
})
```

¿Cómo puedo lograr que **Tailwind** muestre bien la imagen de fondo en el **build**?

**NOTA:** he leído que una solución es colocar esas imágenes en la carpeta **public** y llamarla desde ahí, pero no me gustó esa solución porque cuando genero el **build** queda la imagen por fuera de la carpeta **assets**, además de que afecta la estructura de carpetas de mi sitio ya que las imágenes deben estar en **src/assets/images**

Answer (score -1):

Eso es probema en la ruta del backgroundImage, prueba quitandole ./src, dejandolo ./assets/images/footer-background.jpg, dado que al hacer build generas un code embebido conteniendo lo que está dentro de la carpeta src, so no accedes de modo production a src como tal, por eso puede que no te esté funcionando, testea el método que le comenté.

Comment: Hola, por facor explica con más detalles el porqué consideras que esta respuesta es la correcta, así como trata de explicar objetivamente el como crees que esto puede solucionar el problema.